# My app Xamarin.Android stops responding

Tags: xamarin, crash, xamarin.android

Developed an app using Xamarin.Android that periodically sends the location of the device through an API rest.

I randomly receive the following message in the UI: "My app is not responding, would you like to close it?"

I would like to know how to intercept the cause since I can not intercept it at development time.

Thank you.

Comment: Add a crash reporter to your app, there are numerous one available, here is Microsoft's : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/crashes/

Answer (score 0):

Adding a crash reporter will definitely help you get to the bottom of your issue. Is there a chance that you are calling the REST service from the UI thread? If so, then if there is a network delay, it could "hang" the UI thread, this will result in Android killing the process because it thinks it is no longer working. To get around this issue use:

```
 Task.Run(() => CallYourRESTService());
```

That way your UI thread won't be locked up. Just a suggestion. Of course it's hard to say without seeing a code sample.